# Combining data from plural different data sources at GoodData embedded dashboards

Tags: dashboard, data-integration, gooddata

Is it possible to display combined data from plural different data sources at GoodData embedded dashboards? Or is it only possible to show data from same data source to embedding target system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GoodData embedded dashboards has the same capability in order to data and visualizations as normal "non-embedded" dashboards. All you need to do is to configure your Project to mash up multiple data sources, prepare all Dashboards with your Data and Reports and finally embed this dashboard to the destination system.

To add more functionality to your embedded dashboard you can use for example javascript events to handle different use cases and situations:

https://developer.gooddata.com/article/embedded-dashboard-events